# JGit path filter to support Ant-style or glob patterns

Tags: java, git, jgit

It appears that JGit does not offer path filters that support Ant-style or glob patterns.

- `PathFilter` filters for full paths such as `child-project/foo.txt`
- `PathSuffixFilter` (e.g. `.txt`) filters for path suffixes *in any intermediary path* (catch-all) such as `foo.txt`, `child-project/foo.txt`, or `child-project/src/resources/foo.txt`

Hence, if you want to filter for `child-project/*.txt` - but not `child-project/src/*.txt` - you're out of luck.

I don't see the logic behind offering exactly these two path filters when offering *just a single one* that would support Ant-style or glob patterns would cover all cases.

The documentation in `PathSuffixFilter` hints

> Using this filter is recommended instead of filtering the entries using `TreeWalk.getPathString()` and `endsWith` or some other type of string match function.

To me one doesn't rule out the other. What could be the reason behind that choice?

Comment: TreeFilter is a fairly simple interface, should not be too hard to implement it the way you want for your project. And if it is generally useful then you can even contribute it back to jgit.

Comment: Dominik, thanks for the comment - and your JGit cookbook :)